# How to calculate the probability of two events happening within a certain time period using exponential distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-function

I know how to calculate the probability of one event taking place within a set time period with exponential distribution but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to calculate what would happen if there was a second event that took place within a certain time

For example how would I calculate the probability of two people arriving within 6 minutes when the mean is 3 minutes using exponential distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponential has parameter $\lambda=\frac{1}{3}$.

The number of "events" in a $t$ minute interval has Poisson distribution parameter $\frac{t}{3}$.

Thus the probability of *exactly* $2$ events in a time interval of length $t$ is
$$e^{-t/3}\frac{(t/3)^2}{2!}.$$